# Difference between Spring controller and Endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

Spring boot actuator provides some endpoints like health, metrics, info. It also allows us to write our own custom endpoints.

I have a requirement where I need to expose some Dropwizard metrics stats as an endpoint. Latest Spring-boot does support dropwizard metrics but it does not fit into my requirement, so I am planning to have my own web endpoint `/stats`

But now I am not able to decide whether it should be a normal `Controller` or a custom actuator `Endpoint`. What's the difference between these two terms?

PS: question does seem opinion base, but the answer should be simple enough.

Comment: as I understand (not sure, so only a comment), an `Endpoint` is the Entrypoint for a somewhat "ootb monitoring framework" in spring boot, containing Classes like `HealthIndicator` etc., and "as is" not a controller. Some controller-Functionality can(!) be added by making the `Endpoint` an `MvcEndpoint`, because the concept of serving json-formatted data via http is very close to the one a `@(Rest)Controller` provides. [here](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/10/spring-boot-actuator-custom-endpoint.html) you can find some more insights I think, as well as in the docs. hope this helps?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Endpoints are a more specific or peculiar version of a Controller.

> Rather than rely on a view (such as JSP) to render model data in HTML, an endpoint simply returns the data to be written directly to the body of the response(Similar to doing @ResponseBody in Controller).

Actuator Endpoint is a better option because of the following reasons :

1. Endpoints are meant to perform the highly specific task of printing your Object(Json) on HTTP which is exactly what you want to do here.
2. To separate monitor-n-manage code from your application-specific code.
3. To keep things cleaner and cohesive

Comment: another subtle difference: `@Endpoints` can be sometimes exposed to JMX (vs REST clients/WebFlux etc) `@Controller` is meant to be used in Spring MVC world.